# Generate all combinations (and their sum) of a vector of characters in R

Tags: r, combinations

Suppose that I have a vector of length `n` and I need to generate all possible combinations and their sums. For example:

If `n=3`, we have:

```
myVec <- c("a", "b", "c")

Output = 
"a"
"b"
"c"
"a+b"
"a+c"
"b+c"
"a+b+c"
```

Note that we consider that `a+b = b+a`, so only need to keep one.

Another example if `n=4`,

```
myVec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

Output:
"a"
"b"
"c"
"d"
"a+b"
"a+c"
"a+d"
"b+c"
"b+d"
"c+d"
"a+b+c"
"a+c+d"
"b+c+d"
"a+b+c+d"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `sapply` with varying length in `combn` and use `paste` as function to apply.

```
sapply(seq_along(myVec), function(n) combn(myVec, n, paste, collapse = "+"))

#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c"

#[[2]]
#[1] "a+b" "a+c" "b+c"

#[[3]]
#[1] "a+b+c"


myVec <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
sapply(seq_along(myVec), function(n) combn(myVec, n, paste, collapse = "+"))

#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"

#[[2]]
#[1] "a+b" "a+c" "a+d" "b+c" "b+d" "c+d"

#[[3]]
#[1] "a+b+c" "a+b+d" "a+c+d" "b+c+d"

#[[4]]
#[1] "a+b+c+d"
```

We can `unlist` if we need output as single vector.

Comment: Thank you! Great to see a simple yet efficient solution!